# How To Create 5 columns row in any WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to make a 5 column row in Wordpress, Is anybody help me?

I tried 1/6+1/6+1/6+1/6+1/6 but it's making 6 columns but I need 5 columns

1/6+1/6+1/6+1/6+1/6

I'm getting 6 columns

Answer (score 0):

Please select the custom column in a row and add this 1/5+1/5+1/5+1/5+1/5, you will get your desired 5 columns fully responsive.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this by using bootstrap:

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">One</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 five-col">Two</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 five-col">Three</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 five-col">Four</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 five-col">Five</div>
        <div>lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>

And Use this css : 

.five-col{
    margin-left:4.166666667%
}
```